# How to add pagination in angular project using ngx-pagination and show it's status

Tags: angular, pagination, single-page-application, ngx-pagination

**How to do a pagination status in an angular project like this (dynamically)**

I use [ngx-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination)

[project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufzv28?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't get the problem?  can you explain what is?

Comment: Hi, @MohammadBabaei I have already done pagination in my project. I want to show pagination status dynamically

Comment: what dynamically means in this example?  please provide more info.

Comment: dynamically means when I click '1' in pagination, then the status shows "Showing 1–10 of 100 results", then click '2' in pagination the text change  show "Showing 1–10 of 100 results" to show "Showing 11–20 of 100 results"

Comment: You have page number binded with     (pageChange)="p = $event" to p
And also you have page length and total count so you can calculate and render all header status . Also you can dig in doc mabye there would be output for all values

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution

**Stackblitz** - [my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufzv28?file=app/app.component.html)

> component.html

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>ngx-pagination live demo</h1>
</div>

<div class="list">

  <ul
    *ngFor="
      let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p };
      let ndx = index
    "
  >
    <li>
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="text-center">Showing {{start==null?1:start }} - {{last==null?10:last}} of 100 results</div>

  <pagination-controls
    (pageChange)="listCount($event)"
    (pageChange)="p = $event"
  ></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

> app.component.css

```
:host {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.list {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Console } from '@angular/core/src/console';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  collection = [];
  start;
  last;
  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      this.collection.push(`item ${i}`);
    }
  }
  
  listCount(count) {
    this.start = count
    this.start = this.start * 10 - 9
    this.last = count * 10
    if (this.last > this.collection.length) {
      this.last = this.collection.length;
    }
    console.log('start'+ '      '+this.start + '      '+'last' + '      '+ this.last);
  }
}
```